# Only put certain directories in home to another partition

Tags: partitioning, mountpoint

Before anyone wants to mark this as a duplicate: I do not want to put my /home on another partition.

I'm going to buy a 250GiB SSD to replace the 640GiB HDD in my laptop computer. However, since 250GiB is too less space for my files and the system, I'm going to remove the DVD drive and install the HDD into the now-empty space using a HDD Caddy, where I want to put my files onto.

However, I still want things like `~/.config`, `~/.local` etc. on the SSD, since my HDD is a real performance bottleneck and applications will most likely load faster if all their config is on the SSD. But all other stuff I want on the HDD: Documents, Pictures, Music, ...

Is there any way to accomplish this in a way where I don't notice the partition difference? E.g. I'd like not to mount all my data at e.g. `/media/data`, but I'd like to have the directories from the HDD root mounted 1:1 inside my home. Where and how woud I have to mount the HDD root?

E.g.:

```
/home/username/
    .config/
    .local/
    .PlayOnLinux/ # -> not sure yet
    Documents/ -> HDD/Documents/
    Pictures/ -> HDD/Pictures/
    Downloads/ -> HDD/Downloads/
    .bashrc
    #...
    #Anything undefined to SSD
```

Comment: Just guessing here, cause this is an interesting problem.  I suspect your are going to have to create links from /home/username for the directories which are not located in the physical implementation of /home

Comment: So basically mount the HDD via fstab and create symlinks for each directory on the HDD? That could work, but it doesn't sound really elegant.

Comment: No it doesn't, and I believe some programs do not follow symlinks really well.

Comment: I have done linking like this for years. http://askubuntu.com/questions/223655/windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-share-files-between-os/223670#223670  But have seen one or two suggest using bind as that may work better with networked systems. But mine are not networked. I do use NFS to copy data from one system to another but use under lying file not link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the *mount* command as a **bind** option where you can mount a partition at a second place (sort of)

so you can have in your /etc/fstab something like

```
/dev/sdb3 /media/SSD_home ...
/media/SSD_home /home/username/.config none bind
```

the second line is to bind the mount to the correct place

This has not been tested; it's jsut an idea

Comment: But then anything placed inside `/home/username` goes to the HDD, doesn't it?

Comment: I was thinking about using mounts to do this, but I think that would then entail a separate partition for each directory to be placed in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely possible.

Mount your HDD via fstab.

Modify the `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`in your home directory.

You can modify the entry by changing `XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Picture"` to `XDG_PICTURES_DIR="/<your_pictures_directory>"`.

The same thing goes for any other such directory.

**My setup below:**

[image]

This will also change the bookmarks in the places column so you can easily navigate across directories. Programs also don't have any problem whatsoever.

After this change, the programs will start using the new directories. Though the earlier folders will still exist, they wont be used by any programs. You need to remove them and replace them with symbolic links to your new directories. These symlinks are completely for our convenience only and have no impact on programs.

Comment: If @the_Seppi were to change only the `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file, would thre be an entry somewhere in `~/` that points to the correct location unless he also makes the symbolic link?

Comment: there would be no entry in the present location, because logically, he just moved away those folders to a new place. He definitely has to delete the now redundant folders and create symbolic links to the new ones. The symlinks are just for our convenience only and have no impact on programs.