# Ubuntu on a SSD and everything else on a HDD

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

So I am looking into the future on getting a new computer, one with a 1TB Hard Disk Drive for everything and a Solid State Drive STRICTLY for Ubuntu, I did some research and found out that you have to move each program every time you install it or another one.

I know that in Microsoft Windows you can put the OS on a Solid State Drive and everything else on a Hard Disk Drive (I believe the user files to). I am not aware what Ubuntu's "Programs File(x86)/Programs File x64" equivalent is since it... well does not seem to have one.

I use Steam with a library of 2 to 4 games, 10+ virtual Boxes, a bunch of different programs, including Wine. Wile keeping the Solid State Drive all to Ubuntu (since the OS is read-only, I figured this would work well on a Solid State Drive without wear and tear off the Drive.) So how would I set something like this up? Even for guest users and other users.

And how to install the OS properly to the computer to have the following confuration?

P.S. What do people call that when you have a Solid State Drive as your OS Drive and a Hard Disk Drive as your storage?

Comment: May be related to a question I once asked:http://askubuntu.com/questions/551164/only-put-certain-directories-in-home-to-another-partition

Comment: Also http://askubuntu.com/questions/336439/any-problems-with-this-partition-scheme and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/461394/how-to-partition-ssdhdd

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/516343/move-or-install-apps-on-hdd-not-ssd and http://askubuntu.com/questions/204821/partitions-for-ubuntu-and-windows-7-dual-boot-on-ssd-hdd-setup and http://askubuntu.com/questions/282831/do-i-need-intel-smart-response-when-installing-ubuntu

Answer (score -1):

I have a SSD with with Sheerly Ubuntu and a 1TD HDD set up as a network share on my desko. I haven't had any issues with this setup so far.

The Equivalent to the Program files in Ubuntu is the /etc folder so you would need to format a disk with a mount point of /etc and the system would put that folder there to r/w from.

for you I would recommend putting your /home and /etc on an the separate drive. Also I don't think it's really called anything, You just DO that with your hard drives windows or linux. both user groups do it

Comment: Ehm... the package manager installs programs into `/usr`, not `/etc`

Comment: I thought /usr was for *user specific* packages and then /etc was for packages from  the repo. Then Whoever writes their software for it 3rd party shizz goes into /opt? am I wrong?

Comment: No, user specific packages go into `/usr/local`. It could basically be used interchangably with `/opt`, but if you install something manually or compile it yourselves, use `/usr/local`. Yeah, I know, standards are annoying...

Comment: So,  as a learning moment, what is /etc used for?

Comment: /etc contains lots of config...

Comment: General info on file structure or hierarchy. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Comment: Book marked to read later,  sorry to PF because this has completely rabble trailed

Comment: So how would i do do this through the live installer

Answer (score -1):

Choose the "something else"  option off the installer and create the appreciate mount points on each of your disks

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Will it work as intended if I create a primary partition on SSD with mount point set to `/` and a logical partition on HDD with mount point set to `/home`?