# I have Ubuntu and Windows 8.1 installed on separate SSDs each, any way I can access files in drive on the opposite OS?

Tags: drive

I want to be able to play music from my Ubuntu drive from my Windows 8.1 mainly.

Comment: Best not to access Windows system partition. But create a shared NTFS data partition as d: in Windows and /mnt/data or /media/$USER/shared for any of the default folders of data you may want in both systems. http://askubuntu.com/questions/223655/windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-share-files-between-os/223670#223670

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, actually I am doing this too.

From Ubuntu, this is a piece of cake, as it works out of the box, you just have to mount the drive, and that's it.

Under Windows it is a bit trickier, as Windows cannot read EXT2/3/4 drives by default. However you can install [EXT2FSD](http://www.ext2fsd.com/), which provides a solution for this problem. It provides read and write support too, but just be safe, I recommend to use it for reading only.