# help partition mount and scheme for multiple boot

Tags: boot, partitioning, fstab

I want to have a triple linux boot on my desktop.
For spacing managing issues I'd like to use a partition called sharing.
I want this partition be able to me auto-mount in all distros. How can I do it?

This is my current scheme ( I need to create 2 more paritions, that I'll do on the other setups):

[Partitions scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iESLU.png)

My Fstab is:

```
   # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
   # / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
   UUID=7b9d4f44-0bed-4cac-b3dd-50f1eefc1dd8 /               ext4       errors=remount-ro 0       1
   # /sharing was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=20e3ac2f-6fb5-4e91-9585-dd1ba552beb1 /media/sharing        defaults       0       2
   # swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
   UUID=c49ea5a9-6899-4097-9b38-e78f76ea271b none            swap    sw              0       0
   /dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
```

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/223655/windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-share-files-between-os/223670#223670 Just use /media/sharing as partition to link folders from.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if that is your actual problem but I guess your shared partition is not automatically mounted, is it? That may be because your `/etc/fstab` line for the `/media/sharing` mount point looks incomplete:

```
UUID=20e3ac2f-6fb5-4e91-9585-dd1ba552beb1 /media/sharing        defaults       0       2
```

It seems that the field with the filesystem type is missing (before the mount options field with the current value `defaults`), see also [`man 5 fstab`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/fstab.5.html). Instead, try a line like the following:

```
UUID=20e3ac2f-6fb5-4e91-9585-dd1ba552beb1 /media/sharing        auto    defaults       0       2
```