# shared disk between windows and ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, windows-10, disk, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Windows 10 and want to install Linux ubuntu and I have Tow Storag

SSD 128G HDD 1TB

and I want windows in partition (SSD=48G) and ubuntu in partition (SSD=12G) and my hdd for my documents and photos and videos....ets but I want SSD partition(~50G) for app data and my projects ets (Android Studio) shared between windows and ubuntu mean I put (.android) folder and (sdk)...ets in this partition,mean I don’t need to do two folders for (sdk) or (.android) or (avd emulator) one for windows and one for ubuntu, but I Make this partition shared I can open it and edit from windows and ubuntu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Partition 256 GB SSD for dual Boot, Windows 10 + Ubuntu 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160473/partition-256-gb-ssd-for-dual-boot-windows-10-ubuntu-19-04) and [Partitioning for Windows 10 + Ubuntu + any distro](https://askubuntu.com/q/722038/)

Comment: I see like it, but I don't understand (home) for Linux , where Will be ?

Comment: A separate `/home` partition because it wastes valuable space on the SSD. So do separate `/boot`, `/var`, etc. partitions. Disk space is at a premium on SSDs. This is one of the reasons why a fresh installation of Ubuntu 17.04 and later creates only one ext4 partition which contains a swap file inside it  by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux is very flexible, and indeed you can have the setup you want. The common data partition(s), however, will need to be formatted with a file system that also Windows can access: that means in practice the `ntfs` file format as the only modern and robust file system that both Windows and linux can access.

12G for Ubuntu is a bare minimum, which you may rapidly reach. I recommend at least 15 GB, but better 20GB because you also leave your user configuration data on the system partition.

Your data folders (Documents, Videos, etc,) can all reside on your common ntfs formatted data partition. That way, these files are also available from within Windows.

Move these data folders over to your common data partition. On their original location, put symbolic links that refer to these folders. Symbolic links in Linux are very powerful and, for the user, feel and act exactly like a real folder. Thus, your data remains equally easily accessible from within your home folder, even if it now resides on a different partition. You can do the same for any other folder you want to share between the two operating systems.

**Caveat when working with two operating systems on the same volumes**

- Make sure the file systems on your mounted drives are **regularly checked**. The system partition of Ubuntu is automatically checked. So will be the system partition of Windows (I presume). Your mounted ntfs partitions that contain your data, however, should regularly be checked from within Windows. Only the MS Windows tools are capable to thoroughly inspect and repair the proprietary ntfs file system format.
- Make sure to **shut down Windows completely** (i.e. no hibernation, no fast-start) before using the partitions with Ubuntu. Only then it is ensured that the partitions are correctly closed before you access them with Ubuntu.

Comment: Mean , do I need creat partition /home, and question 2 : where programs are install in Linux ?

Comment: No, /home is on your system partition of 20GB, programs are on the system partition, and only your user data and shared folders are on the shared partitions.

Comment: ok, but ntfs partition is shown in windows but in Linux I don't see it as partition

Comment: You should see it in the left pane of the file manager. Read the caveats I gave carefully.