# Move the boot loader from Windows partition to Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2

Is it possible to format my Windows partition and move the boot record to Ubuntu partition? The reason I want to remove Windows is because I don't have enough space in my Ubuntu and I use Ubuntu in my work.

Here is the result of `sudo fdisk -l`.

```
$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xba8e3544

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    71682047    35840000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        71684094   234440703    81378305    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       220121088   234440703     7159808   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6        71684096   220121087    74218496   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

Is there a way or possible to switch the Boot to `/dev/sda6`? BTW, my Ubuntu version is `14.04`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aren't you using the GRUB boot loader Ubuntu installed to your disk? That one rests in your `/boot` folder on the Ubuntu partition and in the space between the MBR and the first partition. It is not on the Windows partition. That boot flag does not necessarily mean anything if you use GRUB.

Comment: Back up Windows just in case later you want to sell system or have that one application you have to use Windows for. Then  you can delete NTFS and reformat to ext4. I would use as either /home or a /mnt/data partition. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving or this which may be discussing data on separate drive but does not have to be: http://askubuntu.com/questions/223655/windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-share-files-between-os/223670#223670

Comment: @ByteCommander I think it is just the boot menu that is in Windows partition. I am not really in-depth familiar with Linux grub system. Thanks for the clarification.