# Transfering Documents, Pictures, Music, Downloads, Videos from SSD to HDD

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, home-directory, storage

I upgraded my laptop by changing my storage from HDD to SSD (switching from Windows 10 to Ubuntu right after) after I finished building my desktop.  With that spare 2.5" HDD, I decided to remove the DVD player and replaced it with the HDD that was originally in my laptop (everything erased).

Now, I want to know how to move the Documents, Downloads, Pictures, etc. from SSD to HDD. I just want to use the SSD for games & other software

I just wish it was as easy as Windows (I just need to create folders on my HDD and have them redirect to their respective folders).

Comment: Is your HDD plugged into your computer and can you see it in the file manager?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/223655/windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-share-files-between-os/223670?s=12|0.1407#223670 for something similar. Except in your case you can format the hdd as ext4, and not ntfs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you HDD is well formatted and mounted in Ubuntu. In other words, you can access the HDD from a file manager (e.g. Nautilus). You can just create the required folders `Documents`, `Downloads`, `Pictures`, etc. on you HDD. And move your files to these new locations.

Next, there are some things you could do to make things a little more convenient.

For example, you could edit the `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file. This file defines the links to the *special* `Documents`, `Downloads`, etc folders (these are shown in Nautilus on the left). The default content of this file looks like this:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

You can just edit this file to reflect the changes you made.

To resemble the original situation even more, you could add bind mounts to your `/etc/fstab` file. If you go this route, you don't need to change the `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file. You would just bind mount for example the new location of the `Documents` folder (on your HDD), to the original location in your *HOME* folder. You could accomplish this by adding a line like this to your `/etc/fstab`:

```
/<mount-point-hdd>/Documents /home/<user-name>/Documents none rw,bind 0 0
```

Comment: Any way I can change the permission of the fstab?  It's read-only.

Comment: By default `fstab` is not writable by a normal user, this is a good thing. You should not change its permission. You can edit `fstab` by becoming `root`. You can for example edit `fstab` by opening a terminal and typing `sudo nano /etc/fstab`. If you prefer a graphical editor, you could use `gedit` for example: `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`. Changing permissions is done using `chmod` and changing ownership by `chown`, but like I said: you should not change the permissions on `fstab` or system files in general.