# Home folders owned by root

Tags: 16.04, permissions

I recently decided to use ubuntu and for this reason, I followed the steps written in the answer to this question: [Windows Ubuntu dual boot - Share files between OS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223655/windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-share-files-between-os)

Now, I'm new to ubuntu and linux world in general, but from what I've understood, home folders should not be owned by root.
However, after following those steps, that's just what happened: my download, pictures, music and documents folders are all owned by root.
I already found some answers explaining how to change ownership but what I wanted to ask is if I should change it.

Thank to anyone will answer!

Comment: Mmm, maybe I didn't explain myself like I should've. What I did was messing with some config files and using symlinks in order to use folders of an external hard drive like subfolders of home. Those are owned by root.

Comment: I don't think I get it, sorry (as I said, I'm new to ubuntu). The hard drive is connected to a sata port and it's mounted automatically at start up, shouldn't it be already mounted for the user that's using it?

Comment: Then see /etc/fstab. There is where it is configured, probably. add the options to it to mount it as your user. And no... ntfs will be mounted as root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened your provided link, but stopped reading the moment I saw having $HOME (/home/*) files on a NTFS partition (way too scary for me).   I decided long ago ago when I had to dual boot (I no longer do) that it was safer to have a partition (not /home) where both OSes (windoze, ubuntu) could share the files I wanted to access in both worlds.  [My /home was for my gnu/linux distro only; with a link `ln` for easy-access only in $HOME]

As to your real question (file ownership), I'll provide the following

`-rw-rw-r--  1 owner  group    281K Aug 28  2016 file_blah`

I changed my $USER (my username) to "owner" as that field is the owner, which you're saying is "root".  The group that can access it I changed to "group".  I have files in my $HOME (/home/username folder) that are owned by root|root (owner|group), but its not a problem as I have permissions to do what I need with them anyway, as revealed in the "-rw-rw-r--" (owner, group, others).

If it works, I'd leave it just so your version of windoze doesn't complain, but if you want to change it `sudo chown username filename` (where username is your username, or owner you want & filename is name of file/dir, or globbed-regex; eg. *), with a `-R` to quickly do any sub-directories.

But note:  I'd only change it if it's a problem, and I'd save a copy of the directories (`ls -la` at least) so you could write a script to put things back the way they are in case it creates issues for the unnamed windoze version you use.

Comment: It isn't a real problem, because I can just move some files to desktop (that is in an ext4 partition) or create some other subfolders on the hard drive in which I have the /home partition the moment I have to execute some jar or something like that that I don't want to execute as root, I was just wondering if changin ownership could cause any trouble xD And, from what you said, it could be a problem with Windows (I've 10 installed). Anyway, could you please say why it's so scary to mantain my personal files on an external ntfs hard drive?

Comment: I can't offer any advice with regards w10.  Short term you'll likely notice no issues with $HOME anywhere (I used to do things like that long ago too), but I found as you upgraded from one version of gnu/linux to the next (or more likely upgrades after that) quirks & upgrade issues can occur.  ie. its a potential problem you may forget about, but will bite you later :)  I like KISS (keep it simple..)

Comment: Mmm, I see. I will focus on using the system for now and then will try to patch things up xD I'll accept your answer, as the comments clarified other doubts. Again, thank you!