# Custom Home Directory folders (like Desktop, Downloads..)

Tags: 16.04, kernel, directory, customization

How can we create a custom home directory just like Desktop, Downloads.. which is  similar to the screen shot uploaded and the custom directory also displayed like the default directory.

[image]

Comment: unclear. What EXACTLY you want to do

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting or similar: https://askubuntu.com/questions/223655/windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-share-files-between-os/223670#223670

Comment: i need to create a folder which is with custom name and icon same as folders like Desktop , Downloads, Music, Pictures, Videos...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.