# Question related to symlinks

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ntfs, symbolic-link

I have a dual boot system of ubuntu and windows. So to access files of ubuntu on windows I am going to create symlink of the required folders to an ntfs partition.

So my question is can I create the ntfs partition of some random size or it have to be bigger than total size of data inside folder?

eg. Suppose if I want to create symlink of /home/user/Music which contains 1 GB of data to an ntfs partition on same drive, is it necessary to have the ntfs partition greater than 1 GB, or smaller size is sufficient?

Comment: I don't think Windows can read Linux symlinks. Why not just move all your data files from your Home folder to a separate NTFS data  partition, then both systems can read them without worrying about symlinks?

Comment: @PaulBenson See this https://askubuntu.com/a/223670/898816 but I don't know weather symlinks require the same amount of space on disk as the original file or folder.

Comment: Symlinks barely use any space, just a few kb. If you have 2 disks put all data plus Windows on one and Ubuntu on the other. The data should have its own NTFS partition, which is mounted when Ubuntu boots (fstab entry). You can then make symlinks if you want, eg for your desktop, depending how you wish to organize the data.