# Dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 Installation Questions /suggestions alongside Windows 10 in Dell G5

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04

Thanks for checking this post/question.  Mine is a Dell G5 laptop having a 256GB HDD with Intel RAid ON and Installed ubuntu in the additional 1 TB HDD as Ubuntu doesn't allow to install on Intel Raid RST Hard drive. The grub didn't work because of that. So each time I had to go to BIOS boot menu to choose Ubuntu. I lived with it for almost 10 months without any issues. But last week I got a windows update which crashed it. Even Dell tech support couldn't reinstall windows. Thankfully since Ubuntu was still working, I could backup my data and ship it to them to fix it. Now I got my laptop with fresh installation of Windows.

This time I have decided to change the RAID to AHCI before installing Ubuntu and I did it with the help of this Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AIhWnmLx51A.

Now, I'm planning to do the installation as Dual boot alongside the Windows 10 once again. For that, please help me with the below questions:

1. Should I shrink the volume in the 256 GB HDD which has the Windows 10 and Install in the unallocated space in that drive or should I install in the 1 TB additional HDD I have along with it? which will be more stable and safer?
2. When I started the installation process without creating any unallocated space / partition from windows in the 1 TB HDD, Ubuntu installer automatically provided the screen to choose the space from the 1 TB HDD. Is that a good option to try it out? Or should I follow the conventional process I've been following all these years (shrink /delete a partition in Windows to create an unallocated space and then create partitions manually with swap space, etc). Which is better?

Please suggest.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect the 256 GB drive is SSD and is a lot faster than 1TB HDD. If this is true, you should create unallocated space in the 256 GB SSD. Then choose the installation option for side by side. There is no need for a separate swap partition. The default installation process will create a swap file. The rest of the questions are opinion based.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, 256 GB is SSD, so I allocated space and installed Ubuntu in that. It was easy to install without any issues and also it is faster to boot and load. It used to take a lot of time to load previously when it was in the 1 TD HDD.

Comment: I will convert my comment to an answer so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the 256 GB drive is SSD and is a lot faster than 1TB HDD. The answer is based on this assumption.

## Step 1

Create unallocated space in the 256 GB SSD.

## Step 2

Choose the installation option for side by side. There is no need for a separate swap partition. The default installation process will create a swap file.

## Step 3 (Optional)

[Windows Ubuntu dual boot - Share files between OS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223655/windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-share-files-between-os/223670#223670)

Hope this helps